# So sweet with a burning back

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I'm delicious, swoon with sweetness,
But beware my back, you'll burn and perish.

Check my front, it's almost my back,
But with all the cooling waters removed.

Try me, taste me, I'm so sweet,
With variants found in many countries.

If I were wordplay in a crossword,
I'd be grandparental, financial, or a film.

What am I?

Comment: Ah, good to see Rand back in the action :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> **baklava**.

> I'm delicious, swoon with sweetness,

> Baklava is a delicious, sweet pastry.

> But beware my back, you'll burn and perish.

> Its "back" part is molten hot *lava*.

> Check my front, it's almost my back,
> But with all the cooling waters removed.

> Its "front" part is *bak*, which is almost *back*, but with *C*  (Cold) removed. (Alternatively, "cooling waters" can be the *sea*, which is a homophone of *C*.)

> Try me, taste me, I'm so sweet,
> With variants found in many countries.

> This sweet pastry is found across many Middle Eastern and Asian cuisines.

> If I were wordplay in a crossword,
> I'd be grandparental, financial, or a film.

> *Baklava* sounds like "back lava", meaning "lava backwards", i.e., *aval*, which as [Gahja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/115518/48337) found can be grandparental, financial, or a film.

Comment: Yes, that's it! The only thing not quite as I intended is the meaning of "cooling waters" (homophone of that letter?), but yes, you got it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ah, I *see*! Should I change my explanation or add it as an alternative?

Comment: Alternative is fine, yours is good too :-) I'll accept your answer but it might take a while.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> aval, a sweet snack with rice and for example jaggery and coconut, there seem to be many different recipes.

I just got to know you (and it's a pleasure), but of course I knew your back

> "lava" already. In a crossword you might also be a rare synonym for granparental, a guarantee that ensures payment or an Indian horror film.

Comment: Ooh. You've found a relevant word but not the correct final solution. Hint: "my back" doesn't mean "me backwards".